# pull to refresh for a View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

Does anyone know where I can get the code ( open source) for Pull to refresh in a view ( not just a listview).I would like to incorporate it as a common container in my app. Also, would appreciate it if there is "setlastupdated" function which allows to show last updated timestamp.

Thanks! Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some success with [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library.

Comment: is there a pull to refresh that i can use, also a generic pull to refresh that can be applied to all kinds of views ( like listview, views etc)

Answer (score 0):

In general Pull To Refresh is not an Android design pattern. In fact it can be quite annoying, if you are far down a page, and have to go all the way up to the top to refresh.

The Android solution (which is also easier to implement) is a refresh button in the action bar: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html